# new column using paste0() within loop R

Tags: r, loops

I made a loop through my demographics data set to summarise the number of respondents to each question, the number of each type of response and the percentage of each response based based on total responses. The result is each question outputs a df and they are joined at the end of the loop to produce the desired report. I would like to also include a column n_pct by pasting the n (%) for each row. this almost worked except that the data is grouped, I've tried various combinations of apply, but no results. Rather, I get an error about the FUN (using apply) or an attempted list-string as the value:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "n_pct", value = c("c(175, 79) (c(44.5, 40.7)%)",  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 2
```

```
dem_col<-colnames(demographics_df)
dem_col1<-c(3,21,28,29,30,38:43,52,56:58)

sum_dem_df<-demographics_df%>%
  select(site_name,record_id)%>%
  summarise(sum=n(),.groups='keep')%>%
  mutate(question=NA_character_)

#Loop through all columns and get totals by group
for(i in 3:length(dem_col)){
  dem_df_i<-as.data.frame(demographics_df[,c(1,i)])
  name<-paste0(names(demographics_df[i]))
  }if(i%in%dem_col1){
    dem_df_i$j<-dem_df_i[,2] 
    dem_df_i<-dem_df_i%>%
      group_by(site_name)%>%
      drop_na()%>%
      count(j) %>%
      rename(!!name:=j)%>%
      pivot_wider(names_from =!!name,values_from=n )%>%
      mutate(question=!!name)%>%
      replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
      mutate(sum = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))
    dem_df_i<-as.data.frame(dem_df_i)
    dem_df_i$pct<-dem_df_i[,c(2:(length(colnames(dem_df_i))-2))]/dem_df_i$sum
    dem_df_i$n_pct<-paste0(dem_df_i[,c(2:(length(colnames(dem_df_i))-2))],' (',100*round(dem_df_i$pct,3),'%)')
    sum_dem_df<-full_join(sum_dem_df,dem_df_i,by=c('site_name','question','sum'))
  }
```

Code for sample data:

```
demographics_df<-data.frame(site_name=c('city1','city2','city1','city2','city1','city2'),
record_id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
gender.factor=c('male','female','male,'male','trans female',NA_character_),
employment.factor=c('unemployed','unemployed','temporary employed',NA_character_,'unemployed','part-time employed')

desired_df<-data.frame(site_name=c('city1','city2','city1','city2'),
                       sum=c(3,2,3,2),
                       male=c(2,1,NA,NA),
                       female=c(0,1,NA,NA),
                       trans_female=c(1,0,NA,NA),
                       `pct$male`=c(.66,.5,NA,NA),
                       `pct$female`=c(0,.5,NA,NA),
                       `pct$trans_female`=c(.33,0,NA,NA),
                       umemployed=c(NA,NA,2,1),
                       temp_employed=c(NA,NA,1,0),
                       part_time=c(NA,NA,0,1),
                       `pct$unemployed`=c(NA,NA,.66,.5),
                       `pct$temp_employed`=c(NA,NA,.33,0),
                       `pct$part_time`=c(NA,NA,0,.5),
                       n_pct_female=c('0 (0%)','1 (50%)'))
```

note: this is my first time posting a question this complex. Any feedback is valuable. Thank you for your time.

Desired output:
site_name sum male female trans_female pct.male pct.female pct.trans_female umemployed temp_employed part_time
1     city1   3    2      0            1     0.66        0.0             0.33         NA            NA        NA
2     city2   2    1      1            0     0.50        0.5             0.00         NA            NA        NA
3     city1   3   NA     NA           NA       NA         NA               NA          2             1         0
4     city2   2   NA     NA           NA       NA         NA               NA          1             0         1
pct.unemployed pct.temp_employed pct.part_time n_pct_female
1             NA                NA            NA       0 (0%)
2             NA                NA            NA      1 (50%)
3           0.66              0.33           0.0       0 (0%)
4           0.50              0.00           0.5      1 (50%)

Comment: What is `dem_col`

Comment: @akrun edited for clarity. Dem_col is the vector of column names for the data frame.

Comment: Your code had some typos.  I couldn't find the `j` variable `dem_df_i$j<-` in your data

Comment: that is where the variable j is being created. The goal there is to create a column that has the name of the variable from which the multiple choice responses were selected.

Comment: Ok,  but there was some typos which made the code fail i.e. you have `else if` without an `if`

Comment: If you update with expected output, it may have other ways to do instead of a for loop

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there's a better way to do this. My rational for the for loop was that for each variable from demographics_df, there are a variable number of responses (ie, male/female, employed/unemployed/part-time), and the full data set has 47 questions. I looped through to get the total respondents (varies by question), total of each response, percentage of total respondents, and I wanted another column (or rather a column for each response option) with the pasted N(pct%). See edit with desired output if that is helpful.

else if was left over after I simplified